# scala error illegal variable in pattern alternative on pattern matching case

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I am new to scala. I was writing a pattern matching as below:

```
  val capitals = Map("France" -> "Paris", "Japan" -> "Tokyo")
  show(capitals.get("test"))
  def show(x: Option[String]) = x match {
    case Some(s) | None  => s
  }
```

I am getting error:

```
Error: illegal variable in pattern alternative
    case Some(s) | None  => s
              ^
```

I am trying to see how can I achieve or condition like I have in if statement in java

> if (str == null || str.isEmpty())

Can you help rewrite the code or point out the mistake?

Question: How do I mention or condition in a case pattern matching?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how you pattern match on Options:

```
def show(x: Option[String]) = x match {
  case Some(s) => s
  case None => "N/A"
}
```

(by the way, you can also do something like this):

```
capitals.get("test").getOrElse("N/A")
```

Now, to add OR conditions to a pattern match case, you cannot use bound variables. This will work, however:

```
def show(x: Option[String]) = x match {
  case Some(_) | None => "a"
}
```

Note that the only difference is in `Some(_)` as opposed to your `Some(s)`. Using `Some(s)` wouldn't make much sense because you can't reuse that `s` anyway (what if `None` comes, what would `s` be in that case?)

Comment: this is informative. what I am trying ti achieve with is? ignoring this scenario..is or statement is possible? I have three case saying case Some[], case None, case _ . Instead writing three cases, i wanted to find if I can give it as or. Like I wanted do an operation on a or condition.How do i achieve it instead writing two cases?

Comment: thanks for the insightful answer. this is what exactly I am looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to reduce something like this:

`intOpt match {
  case Some(i) if (i < 2) => true
  case None => true
  case _ => false
}`

into `... case None | Some(_) if (_ < 2) => true` somehow?

Comment: @ristohietal I'm not sure, because "if" part doesn't make sense in case of None. But I also personally wouldn't like it even if it were possible. Your statement with three distinct cases makes perfect sense and is easier to read. Perhaps putting the `None` case before `Some(i) if (i < 2)` case makes it even easier to read and understand. Of course, this is all highly subjective.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve. If `s` has a value in the map return, `s`. If `s` has no value in the map, return a message indicating so.

```
val capitals = Map("France" -> "Paris", "Japan" -> "Tokyo")

def show(x: Option[String]) = x match {
  case Some(s)  => s
  case None     => "x has no value"
} 

show(capitals.get("mani"))
```

A similar and more concise version of `show` is `capitals.get("mani").getOrElse("No value found")` which returns
`No value found`.

Further, you can use a guards to check various conditions on `s` such as if the first char is upper case. This first case will only match if `s` begins with an upper case character.

```
 def show(x: Option[String]) = x match {
     case Some(s) if(s.head.isUpper) => s
     case None     => "No value"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Matching `Some(s) | None` doesn't make sense, as `if (true || false)` (just no-op as it doesn't dispatch cases).

```
x match {
  case Some(s) => println(s"Some($s)")
  case _ => println("_None")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most direct solution is using [the method defined for maps](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/MapLike.html#getOrElse(key:K,default:=%3EV):V), which takes the default as the second argument:

```
capitals.getOrElse("test","N/A")
```